# Embedded Mongo migration from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, embedded-mongodb

I was using **de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.5.0**

I have created EmbeddedMongoServer class, where I am importing
**MongoProcess
MongodStarter
Defaults
MongodConfig
RuntimeConfig
MongodExecutable**

However, I want to upgrade my internal mongo library from springboot 2.7 to 3.1.1 and when I replaced flapdoodle to **flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x:4.5.2** It can not find the above mentioned classes/interfaces. How can I successfully migrate ?

I am trying with **flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x:4.5.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this today. You didn't mention it, but just in case, you need both flapdoodle embed mongo and the spring30x test libraries.

Here's what I did for mine.

Assuming you are using:

```
Java 17
spring-web: 3.1.0
spring-data-mongodb: 3.1.0
```

Test Libs

```
testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:4.7.1'
testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x:4.7.0'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
```

**test/resources/application-test.yaml**

```
de:
  flapdoodle:
    mongodb:
      embedded:
        version: 4.4.18
        storage:
          repl-set-name: rs0
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: test
```

And based on their [samples](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.canary/blob/main/embed-spring-boot-30/src/test/java/example/ExampleIT.java):

```
import me.com.MyApplication;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.AutoConfigureDataMongo;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;



@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = MyApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK
)
public class ExampleIT {
    @Test
    void example(@Autowired final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(mongoTemplate.getDb());
        ArrayList<String> collectionNames = mongoTemplate.getDb()
          .listCollectionNames()
          .into(new ArrayList<>());
        assertThat(collectionNames).isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

or a sliced test

```
import me.com.MyApplication;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DataMongoTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class ExampleIT {
    @Test
    void example(@Autowired final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(mongoTemplate.getDb());
        ArrayList<String> collectionNames = mongoTemplate.getDb()
          .listCollectionNames()
          .into(new ArrayList<>());
        assertThat(collectionNames).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- These flapdoodle properties are setup for my production MongoDB version which is also setup as a replica set.
- I use profiles to setup different Mongo configurations; local, vs AWS, vs test. If your setup is different, you might not need the `@ActiveProfiles`
- I am also using Mongock for migrations and it requires journaling to be turned on. Since replica sets enable this by default, I didn't need to do anything else. However, if you aren't in RS mode, look at customizing your command options. Something like this might get you there.

```
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.commands.MongodArguments;

@Bean
MongodArguments mongodArguments() {
    return MongodArguments.builder().useNoJournal(false).build();
}
```

Comment: Just a note - don't add the port config (don't even set it to zero) otherwise down the road MongoClient is throw exception that port zero isn't correct. It will work fine w/o port config.